# Error in selenium mvn project : Cannot find class in classpath:

Tags: java, selenium, maven, automated-tests

1. I installed a selenium environment at work with an eclipse
2. When I open the mvn project I get an error that the source is not Java.
3. When I try to do this : Project Facets> Convert to Faceted Form, and select Java. To change to Java I do not have this option.
4. When I set up a regular Java project and do a conversion to mvn and run a test from it I get the error:
   **Cannot find class in classpath:**
   Can anyone please help me with this? I have already tried a lot of things, including cleanliness, compile and nothing helps.
   **I need to say its happened even if I run simple single test from the test and not from the testNG.xml**
   Thanks in advance

[image: the error]

Comment: Can you right click on project Run As --> Maven generate sources to recreate all the class files

Answer (score 0):

We may encounter Cannot find class in classpath exception while executing tests in Selenium with TestNG framework. This can be caused because of the following reasons −

1. In the TestNG XML, the class tag having the name attribute should
   not have the .java extension.
2. In the TestNG XML, the class file is incorrect and hence unable to
   determine the classpath of the class.
3. Errors within the project are present, and may require a clean
   project.
4. In the TestNG XML, the class file name is incorrect

Comment: Sorry Its not the issue - Its happened also when there is no testNG.xml its happened from the test itself when I am trying to run it from there

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird error I have had so many times working with testNG. Here is the solution :

Do maven update as a pre-requisite :

1. Right click on project and go to Run as
2. Select maven clean
3. Now go to
4. Project from Eclipse menu bar (File, Edit, ...)
5. Click on Clean
6. Select your Project Click on Clean

[image]

Comment: Thanks but didn't help for me

Comment: @mb13  :Did you do maven update beforehand ?

Comment: Yes I did - there is no change